# Making sure the user enters a particular file type

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I have a JFileChooser (not shown here) that takes a users file Input. I would like to make sure the user enters only a .txt file. Is there a function available that allows this to be verified with JFileChooser or another possible solution. I considered the following:

```
if (selectedFile != null && selectedFile.getName().endsWith(".txt")){
    //action
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have not selected a .txt file. Please choose a correct file type to continue.);
}
```

However, if it is possible, I would like for it to be the case that even if the file does not explicitly end with .txt in the name, it will still be accepted but it must still be a text file.

Answer (score 1):

Answer, how to detect if a file is actually .txt file you can use Apache Tika library for that

```
public static void main(String[] sss) {

        try {
        //  System.out.println(ContainsMedia(new File("D:\\test")));

            Tika tika = new Tika();
            String contentTypeDetected = "";
            File dir = new File("D:\\test");
            for (String dir2 : dir.list()) {
                try {

                    contentTypeDetected = tika.detect(new File(dir,dir2));
                    System.out.println(contentTypeDetected);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

output:text/plain
even though the file in that directory is text file but i renamed it to .exe file and .rar file but the apache tikka tell the truth
for download here is the link of jar add it to your classpath after downloading [Apache tikka homepage](https://tika.apache.org/)

Secondly if you want him to choose only txt file type you can do

```
fileChooser.setFileFilter(new FileFilter() {

            @Override
            public boolean accept(File f) {
                if (f.isDirectory())
                    return true;
                String name = f.getName().toLowerCase();
                return name.endsWith(".txt") 
                        ;
            }

            @Override
            public String getDescription() {
                return "only text file";
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

See JavaDoc for using [FileFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setFileFilter(javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter).) with JFileChooser.

You need to implement custom FileFilter that not only will check the file name extension but also check if file content is a text.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.
The JFileChooser provides everything you need.

For example:

```
    jfc.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

    jfc.setFileFilter(new FileFilter()
    {
        @Override
        public String getDescription()
        { return "*" + fileExtension; }

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File f)
        {
            return f.isDirectory() || f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(fileExtension));
        }
    });
```

(jfc is the JFileChooser object, created before.)

This is a really simple example.
As you can see, you have to add a new FileFilter to solve your problem.
This Object got a method called "accept", which just returns a boolean value
(whether it is a "valid file" or not.)

But you should check the Java Documentation about it for all the possibilities.

Or use these tutorials provided by Oracle:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html

Btw. you cannot ensure that the chosen file containts just text.
You would have to check this afterwards.

Good luck!
(It wont be that hard to achieve ;D)

Comment: Thank you very much for the help :)